In a Laravel Project, is it safe to have .htaccess file in the public folder?
I ran my Laravel project through Zap Scanner Application and it stated ".htaccess Information Leak" as a medium level risk. When I type http://127.0.0.1:8000/.htaccess in the browser, it shows following:
`


Options -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


`
I am not sure if it is normal, or I should move the .htaccess to different folder? If so there where I should place it?

how are you serving your application?

@krisgjika, I am new to programming. Not sure what do you mean? I am running the project by running command,php artisan serve and npm run div in visual studio editor....

what is the point on running a scanner on a development server? use a proper sever like apache if you are concerned with that

@krisgjika Thank you for your feedback. you are right, local-server is not same as live server.

Yes this is secure because Apache does not make files starting with a dot, like '.htaccess' public.
